Python rectangle somehow being overwritten
This is not a question about how to draw rectangles in PyGame. But somehow my code is overwriting what I am drawing so that when I attempt to draw a large green rectangle marker on my map, I only see a single pixel (in green) added to the map.
Here is the command that I am using:
pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 1000, 1000))

I only get a 1x1 rect, and not the expected 1000 x 1000.
Same for those:
pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, x + 1000, y + 1000))
pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), ((x, y), (x + 1000, y + 1000)))
pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), ((x, y), (1000, 1000)))

They all draw a 1x1 rectangle. Why is that?
I do see the rectangle and the position is right. Only the size is causing trouble.
Full code:
import pygame, os, sys, ast
pygame.init()
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
txt_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "map.txt")
zoom = 1
with open(txt_path, "r") as file:
    data = file.read()
data = result = ast.literal_eval(data)
display = pygame.display.set_mode((len(data), len(data[0])))
x = 0
for line in data:
    x += 1
    y = 0
    for pixel in line:
        y += 1
        if pixel == 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 0, 0), (x* zoom, y * zoom, x* zoom + zoom, y * zoom + zoom))
        elif pixel == 2:
            plus = 200
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 100, 100))
            print(x, y)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(display, (255, 255, 255), (x* zoom, y * zoom, x* zoom + zoom, y * zoom + zoom))
        
while True:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

Output:

The green pixel is in Turkey
The file is only a list which contains the data for the map.

Sadly they never do! Can you give a mimal complete program that illustrates the problem, as there seems to be nothing wrong with the lines of code you have put up.

@Lee-xp I can send the full code, it's 30 lines long. Is that ok?

Looking at your complete code, there is no line that reads: pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 1000, 1000)) as in your earlier posting.

It's pygame.draw.rect(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y, 100, 100))

Sorry, I forgot to tag you. @Lee-xp

Your code is hard to test without the image. Any ideas?

@Lee-xp What do you mean?

@Lee-xp In case you want the file, I don't know how to send it...

@Lee-xp I could write it in the question, but it is a bit long...

No I can't actually it is too long

Try putting it in the question, otherwise no one can really test your code very easily.

OK - can you mock up some very simple data (included in the code) that still demonstrates the problem?

@Lee-xp Here! needed some time... https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Qualcuno2/Test/main/README.md

@Lee-xp Anyways, thanks for the interest!

So annoying it has been closed!! Now I have the full code I can see what is happening. If you comment out the cases where pixel is not 2. You can see what is going on. I also added a 2 to your data at the very first position. You will see that you do get a large green rectangle, but normally it is overwritten as the black and whit pixels are laid down. To fix the problem, just go through the data twice. The first time respond to pixel=0 and pixel=1. The second pass, respond to pixel=2. Then your green rectaangles can be as large as you want.

@Lee-xp Ooooh I am so dumb thanks!!!!!!! I'll just need to write another function

Glad to help. And the silly thing is that in closing your question they simply reference a question about how to draw a rectangle. Nothing to do with your issue at all, which was legitimate, and needed answering - and was absolutely not a duplicate.

I have flagged the issue of wrong closure, and I was prompted to edit the question to clarify that it was not asking how to draw a rectangle. So I hope you don't mind my edit - which apparently will be reviewed, with the possibility of reopening the question (the edit is not visible until it has been reviewed and accepted). But worth a shot.

@Lee-xp Thanks, but I am worried I accepted it and it did not open it... anyways, I had proposed a re - opening half an hour ago, let's see...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is code to draw a rectangle.
import pygame

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the window
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:
    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Draw a green rectangle (x, y, width, height)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, (50, 50, 200, 100))

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()

And this is the result:


But why aren't my commands working?

without the full context (for a MRE), it is hard state why. Hence a working example in the answer.

Done! Here are also some extra caracters.

@D.L I think StackOverflow should do some mechanism, people couldn't downvote without any comment. I see same type of issue sometimes ...

@ArtBindu , ageed, especially when the answer is a valid working answer.  your comment is upvoted !

Somebody had a bad day.

@D.L Since you have XP enough, could you reopen the question, as it clearly is not a duplicate? Thanks!

it might be more efficient to re-ask a new question. generally, a good guide is here: how to ask . it seems that users are quick to close or mark down what they consider to be poor questions.
